# Swift: what's the difference between Array<OtherModule.MyType>() and [OtherModule.MyType]()

Tags: swift

I'm using a type from a different module, let's call it OtherModule.MyType,

This code:

```
var a = [OtherModule.MyType]()
```

will produce an error `invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[MyType.Type]'`

This code won't:

```
var ax = [OtherModule.MyType]
```

But I believe `ax` is not an array any more, since this code

```
ax.append(OtherModule.MyType())
```

will cause an error `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of '(MyType)'`

So I wonder what `ax` really is?

Besides, this code works fine:

```
var ay = Array<OtherModule.MyType>()
ay.append(OtherModule.MyType())
```

**UPDATE**:
I'm using swift 1.2 with Xcode 6.3

Comment: There should not be any difference, since `[T]` is an alias for `Array<T>`. It may be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason best known to the Swift team (modules are very scantly documented), `Module.Thing` behaves differently to `Thing`.

While `Int` is just a type name:

```
let i: Int = 1  // fine
// not fine, "expected member name or constructor call after type name"
let j = Int
```

`Swift.Int` can be both:

```
// used as a type name
let k: Swift.Int = 1
let t = Swift.Int.self

// but also used as a value
let x = Swift.Int
// equivalent to this
let y = Int.self
toString(x) == toString(y) // true
```

Under some uses it only wants to be a value, not a type name though.  Hence this works:

```
// a will be of type [Int.Type], initialized with an array
// literal of 1 element, the Int metatype
let a = [Swift.Int]
```

But trying to use it as a type name in this context fails: `[Swift.Int]()` is no more valid than writing `[1]()` or `let strs = ["fred"]; strs()`.

This behaviour seems a little arbitrary, and may even be a bug/unintentional.

Since the *only* way in which `Swift.Int` can be used in this context:

```
Array<Swift.Int>()
```

is as a type not a value (since only types can go between the angle brackets), it kind of makes sense that this works while the more ambiguous array literal syntax behaves differently.